# How return value not array with values using leftJoin in createQueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, typeorm, query-builder

I have query where I have two left joins. So left join return me array with object, but I know that value which come from left join will be just one. So my question is can I make left join and if value will be found return not object but just value?

now I have series: [{id: 5}]

what I want to do series: 5 - just value

or if it possible return just true of false series: true

```
.createQueryBuilder('sr')
    .select(['sr.id','sr.name', 'srv.id' 'ser.id'])
    .distinct(true)
    .leftJoin('sr.scoringRuleValues', 'srv')
    .leftJoin('sr.series', 'ser', 'ser.scoringRuleId = sr.id') // this join I need to improve
    .where('sr.valueId =:valueId',
.getMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getRawMany()` to not return an array with object